# Animators may only be run on Looper threads error on ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am having a problem with

```
{
    AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animSet.start();
}
```

Getting crash after `animSet.start`

Getting msg `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads...`

Please help me to overcome this issue..

Comment: read some material about Looper class

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        animSet.start();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 100);
```